# Tapestry textfield updating server data in grid

Tags: tapestry

I have a tapestry grid on web ui, on column contains text field to make user able enter value for specific row, i need to handle event when user entered value and save it value to database on server side right after update, i do not need any ajax features

Thanks

Comment: What do you have already? maybe this can help: http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/tables/editablegridforupdate1